# Change in index.html doesn't reflect

Tags: html, tomcat, caching

This looks bizarre to me. A line in an HTML file is deleted (`<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/xyz.css"/>`) and a new build is deployed in QA. Manually checked the HTML in deployment and verified that the change is reflected in the new deployment.

However, when accessing through a browser the line `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/xyz.css"/>` is still there. Cleared the browser cache, restarted the app server but no success. Eventually the file xyz.css had to be deleted to achieve the desired result. The specs are as below:

1. OS: SMP Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2
2. App server: Tomcat 8.5.28
3. Java: 1.8.0_161
4. Browsers tried - Chrome: 65.0.3325.181 & 67.0.3383.0; Firefox: 59.0.2 Opera: 52.0; MS Edge: 41.16299.248.0

I suspect the HTML file is cached somewhere but can't put my fingers on it. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Is it a static file? Did you try deleting tomcat work folder between deployments?